# Localized string in rails app with RTL language and numbers - how to make numbers show up on correct side of text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, right-to-left

I have a Rails 7 app with localization in a RTL language. I want to display a localized string that contains a number (right) followed by text (left).

Instead no matter what order I type the input, the string is shown as text (right) followed by the number (left) in both the code editor and the rendered website.

**config/locales/he.yml**

```
he:
  parks:
    _filters_index:
      parks_count:
          zero: 'פארקים 0'
          one: 'פארק 1'
          other: '%{count} פארקים'
```

**app/views/parks/_filters_index.html.erb**

```
<%= t("parks._filters_index.parks_count", :count => @parks.count) %>
```

Comment: Are you using the correct [CSS text direction property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)?

Comment: How would I use the CSS text direction property so that it changes depending on the locale? Is that not built into the locale itself? The issue I'm having is specifically when the last item in the string is a number.

Comment: I'm not sure how people actually do it. There is a [`lang` psuedo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) but I could imagine that you could just have an additional stylesheet thats loaded conditionally or have a class thats added to the body tag based on the locale.